# Mocking method reference as any

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock this line:

```
ResponseEntity<String> response= gatewayOutWrapper.wrap_2P_OneWay(GatewayOut::getConnectionType, wit, serialNumber, metaData);
```

with `when(gatewayOutWrapper.wrap_2P_OneWay(GatewayOut::getConnectionType, any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseBody));`

But i dont know how to mock method reference as any. I tried some real values, but i alway get null when run test on that line, so this when dont fire.

Can anyone Help?

Comment: Have you tried `when(gatewayOutWrapper.wrap_2P_OneWay(any(), any(), any(), any()))`? It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer is that `any()` should work fine, as Lesiak mentioned in the comments. Java represents method references as [implementations of single-method interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963341/1426891), and `any` can mock those interfaces just fine.

You might have found [other Mockito pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891):

- If you use a matcher like `any` for any argument when stubbing or verifying, you have to make sure all arguments use matchers. Passing a real value, including your method reference, next to matchers like `any()` is not allowed. `eq` is the default, so you can wrap with that.
- If `gatewayOutWrapper`'s class is `final`, you need to opt-in to [final mocking support](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39), or else the `null` values (that matchers like `any()` return) will make their way to a real implementation. This is supported in Mockito 2.1+, but it's still not the default behavior as of Mockito 5.
- You might also be getting a null pointer exception if `gatewayOutWrapper` is a spy or it calls real methods; the solution is to use `doReturn` as in:

  ```java
  doReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseBody))
      .when(gatewayOutWrapper)
      .wrap_2P_OneWay(any(), any(), any(), any());
  ```